# How to make firebase text bold?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android app with a firebase real-time database. I want to show some recent articles about ther. Is there any way to make the text bold I want? Also, how can I change the paragraph or use line break in the firebase database?

The sample texts are below

**Google deserts desserts: Android 10 is the official name for Android Q**

Google has officially named the next version of Android, which is due to be released this fall: Android 10. Breaking the 10-year history of naming releases after desserts, the company is bailing on providing a codename beginning with a subsequent letter of the alphabet (in this case, Q), which is the way we’ve been referring to Android up to now. This year is Android 10, next year will be Android 11, and so on.

After a quarter of quiet, the quintessence of Android’s brand has quickly changed without quarrel, resolving a quandary and quitting the quixotic quest to pull a Q dessert out of the quiver. Google won’t quaver on the decision to move away from desserts, which answers a quadrillion querulous questions about the names.

Google has decided it is a quaint tradition that needed to be quite quashed — or at least quelled. Instead, the codename will be quarantined inside Google, so I have qualms and feel queasy about the number of quips that will queue up quoting the Android source code in an attempt to quibble that the dessert names still qualify as real. It all seems like a quagmire, but at least qualitatively, the new naming scheme is less quirky.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a markdown inside your App but Firebase is not designed for this feature and shouldn't be used as such as this would essentially corrupt your data with inline code - You instead will want to make it bold within your app, either globally or on a per case basis.

All you need to do is research your framework and language and find out how to enable bold text.

Comment: Noted. Thank you so much.